# ASP.NET: Themes : Associating a CSS file out side App_Theme folder for Skin/Theme

Tags: asp.net, themes, skinning

Is there anyway i can mention which CSS file should be attached to my Page automatically when running A Page with ASP.NET Themes /Skins ? I want to associate my own CSS which resides in a folder other than the APP_Themes Folder to the Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link href="styles/common/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```